# How to use linq extensions methods using Expression.Call

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

Here's a simple example of what i'm facing:

```
            Expression<Func<Company, bool>> func = a => a.Name == "foo bar";
            var exp = Expression.Call(typeof(IQueryable<Company>), "Where",
                new[] { typeof(Company) }, func);
```

When i run this code, i get this message:

```
No generic method 'Where' on type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[BBM.Domain.Entities.Core.Company]' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.
```

I'm not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

`Where` is actually an extension method on type [`System.Linq.Queryable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.where?view=netcore-3.1). The easiest way to get it (due to `Queryable` having 2 overloads which differ only in number of generic parameters in `Expression<>` in predicate) , I would say would be just using another expression:

```
Expression<Func<IQueryable<int>, IQueryable<int>>> expr = x => x.Where(y => true);
var mi = ((MethodCallExpression)expr.Body).Method;
```

But I would say that it seems you don't actually need to do that, cause you can just create `Call` expression by hand:

```
Expression<Func<Company, bool>> func = a => a.Name == "foo bar";
Expression<Func<IQueryable<Company>, IQueryable<Company>>> call = x => x.Where(func);
```